# Programmatically read linux kernel parameters

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am modifying a Linux driver and I'd like to programmatically read the parameters passed to kernel... in other words, my driver should act in a different way if a specific parameter is passed to Linux kernel at boot...

How can I do that?

Have I to read them from `/proc/cmdline` and then program my logic? Or is there an API to be called for reading and parsing kernel parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use __setup() macro.
See for example `__setup("ip=", ip_auto_config_setup);` in net/ipv4/ipconfig.c

Comment: can you provide some additional details? I took a look at `net/ipv4/ipconfig.c` but it is not clear to me...

Comment: It's rather simple. You declare this macro to match a string to a handler.

The string can be anything unique, such as "my_freq=".
The handler should be a static fuction that parses the value after "="

In the above example, see the implementation of ip_auto_config() to parse the IP parameters (ip, netmask, serverip, gateway, netdev, ...)

Comment: One important thing is that you should build the driver statically into the kernel for this to work. It will not work for modules (.ko) because `__init` part is ignored for modules. Secondly, if you are using a recent kernel like 4.x+, prefer `MODULE_PARAMS()` since `__setup` is deprecated if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Linux boot time command line is copied into a  global variable called saved_command_line . It is defined in init/main.c.

Just read the variable in your module.